# Replacing entire DIV with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, html-table

I'm attempting to start a div area with html in it and then replace that html with new html. I am currently trying to do so with the use of a function to simplify the creation of the html.

This is my function that creates a table based on input of rows and columns and a character.

```
function drawArt (x, y, char){
    $( "#artArea").append("<table>");

    indexY = 0;

    while (indexY < y)
    {
        $( "#artArea").append("<tr>");
        var indexX = 0;
        while (indexX < x)
        {
            $( "#artArea").append("<td class=tableCell>" + char + "</td>");
            indexX++;
        }
        $( "#artArea").append("</tr>");
        indexY++;
    }
    $( "#artArea").append("</table>")
};
```

I'd like to be able to recall this function to redraw the table. So far this is what I have written but it seems to not work. Any tips?

```
$( "#genNew" ).click(function(){

    var xGlobal = $("#numCols").val();
    var yGlobal = $("#numRows").val();
    var charGlobal = $("#drawChar").val();

    $( "#artArea" ).replaceWith();
    drawArt (xGlobal, yGlobal, charGlobal);
})
```

So, as suggested below changing "replaceWith" to "empty" fixed part of my problem. However, it broke another part of my program. I should be able to click on any character and get it to change to whatever was input, without changing the whole table, as so:

```
$( ".tableCell" ).click(function(){
charGlobal = $("#drawChar").val();
$(this).text(charGlobal)
})
```

Which part of my program is failing?

Comment: can you add a fiddle

Comment: A fiddle? I don't think I understand. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: `$( "#artArea" ).replaceWith();` to `$( "#artArea" ).empty()`.

Comment: Or, change your first `$( "#artArea").append("<table>");` to `$( "#artArea").html("<table>");`.  Or, build the whole html in a string and make a single `.html(str)` at the end.

Comment: @JoeySides If you have a fiddle setup, others can respond easily. More people will look into your code if you have a fiddle setUp. Thats the only reason. That way you get quick and better answers

Comment: Wait - you had a problem - the comments (and dubious, but valid, answer) provided a working, viable solution - so you edited the question with a new, completely different problem?  That's not how SO works!  You should ask the commenter (@RLam) to create an answer so you can mark it as correct and then ask a *new* question.

Comment: My apologies. I was in the process of creating a fiddle so that the answer can be fully compatible with my program. I, unfortunately, don't know how to use this "fiddle" tool. That is the only reason I updated my original post.

Comment: For your second question, `$( "#artArea").append("<td class='tableCell'>" + char + "</td>");`. Just add single quote for tableCell. Also, it will be better to add `var` to make it as local variable

Comment: @RLam - it has nothing to do with that - it's because those elements are added after the `click` event is attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem is you're creating invalid html. You always append to the `#artArea` table, so your markup will end up as

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
... etc
</table>
```

This is not what you want. What I suggest you could do is to simply create the appropriate html as a string inside `drawArt` and use `replaceWith to change the html

```
function drawArt (x, y, char){
    var html = "<table>";

    indexY = 0;

    while (indexY < y)
    {
        html += "<tr>";
        //-- snip, you get the idea!
    }
    html += "</table>"
    return html;
}
```

and then

```
$( "#genNew" ).click(function(){

    var xGlobal = $("#numCols").val();
    var yGlobal = $("#numRows").val();
    var charGlobal = $("#drawChar").val();

    $( "#artArea" ).html(drawArt (xGlobal, yGlobal, charGlobal));    
})
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/0sh1wt01/1/

---

Having updated the question with a new requirement, I should address that too. The reason your `click` event handler does not work on the table cells is that `click` only affects elements which are on the page at the time the page loads. if you're dynamically adding new elements (as we are above) then you need to delegate the event to an element which *does* exist at page load. In this case we could use the `artArea`. Note you want `.html` not `.text`

```
$( "#artArea" ).on('click','.tableCell', function(){
    charGlobal = $("#drawChar").val();
    $(this).html(charGlobal);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/0sh1wt01/2/

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working for me. I even tried directly replacing my code with your working example and it won't redraw the table after clicking the button. Would seeing my full code help?

Comment: @JoeySides - that is because you have completely replaced the `artArea` div with the table (thats what `replaceWith` does). If you want to just insert the new table *inside* the `artArea` use `.html` in place of `.replaceWith` eg. http://jsfiddle.net/0sh1wt01/1/

Comment: So, changing ".replaceWith" to ".html" now allows me to resize the table art, but now prevents me from clicking on individual cells to change its contents. Any advice with that? See original post edit for example code.

Comment: Didnt see you'd updated the question, i'll update the answer to answer that. See update now.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the html with a new one.

This is the js code:

```
$("#start").click(function() {
  var x = $("#rows").val(),
      y = $("#columns").val(),
      charx = $("#char").val();
//getting teh no of columns, rows and the character

  $("#container").html("");
//empty the container first

 var table = document.createElement("table");
 for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) {
       var td = document.createElement("td");
       td.innerHTML = charx;
       tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
 }
//creating the table based on the values

 $("#container").append(table);
//appending inside the container

});
```

Here is the [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/61E7sXdKWvgHzkekSyY5?p=preview)

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and vanilla javascript? That's just confusing to an inexperienced dev!

Comment: Why mix jquery and javascript DOM manipulation?  Why not just use jquery?